# Formula to compare data sets for a possible partial string match

Tags: worksheet-function

I'm trying to compare two large sets of data (ex. Set 1 and Set 2) for a limited match in string (say first 5 letters matching between column A and D). If a match is found a new column F would populate with the value of an adjacent cell from Set 1.

See test image where I'm trying to have column F automatically populate with the string in column B if there is a match found between data in column A and D.

I can use Excel, Google Sheets, or Libre Office

[Test Data showing goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCU4K.png)

Comment: Great question. Welcome to SuperUSer! Lots of good info here. Visit often to improve your skills.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the **VLOOKUP** command. I know it's available in Excel & Libre Office. Not sure about Google Sheets -- probably something similar there.

> VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, column_index_num, range_lookup)
>   The VLOOKUP function performs a vertical lookup by searching for a value in the first column of a table and returning the value in the same row in the index_number position.

Now, let's convert that into words for your example:
In sheet 2, you want to see if the account exists in sheet 1. If it does, show the name from Sheet 1.

For cell F3:
lookup_value is D3
table_array is A3..B7
column_index_num is 2.
range_lookup is True or False
  Optional. Enter FALSE to find an exact match. Enter TRUE to find an approximate match. If this parameter is omitted, TRUE is the default.

Caveats: VLOOKUP will always search the left-most column of table_array for a match.
  The left-most column of table_array must be sorted alphabetically.
  For column_index, 1 is the left most column of table_array.

Here's a link for more information:
[How To Use VLOOKUP](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php)

Comment: Thank you for this. One follow up question: Is there a way to look for a partial match with a limit of, say, 5 matching characters.  If the result is mostly matching it gives a the value from Set 1 and if not close to matching reports a blank?

Comment: Matching ANY 5 characters, or just the FIRST 5?

Comment: If you can do any 5 of the total string, that would be great. If not, the first 5 would be second best...

Comment: For the first 5 characters, the lookup_value changes from D3 to left(D3,5). Make sure range_lookup is either TRUE or empty.

Comment: Notice that this will take the first 5 of D3 and match it to ANY 5 in A3. Is that what you want?